# JS: Keep variable values for onclick event attached inside for loop

Tags: javascript

I want the onclick function to remember the value of the variable i and j in the for loop at the instance the onclick function is called. However the variables update before they are stored in the onclick function.

I am making a Tic Tac Toe application and don't want to manually add all the onclick statements as that would be a bad practice for larger projects.

```
for (j = 0; j < Columns; j++) {

    var col = document.createElement("td")
    row.appendChild(col)
    col.id = i + "" + j;
    col.onclick = function() {
        console.log(i, j)
        place(i + "" + j)
    }    
}
```

There are no error messages but I don't know how to save the variables the instance the onclick function is called. How can I save the variables when the onclick function is called?

Comment: ```for (j = 0; j < Columns; j++)``` Remember to use ```let```: ```for (let j = 0; j < Columns; j++)```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must scope your variables declaring it by the use of `let`, that way you'll scope it exclusively for that iteration. Avoid to declare a variable like `i = 0`, bacause that way you create a global variable and it will not work (throw an error) on `'use strict'` cases.

```js
let Columns = 3
let rows = 3
const table = document.getElementById("table")

for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {  
  let row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.textContent = "row " + i;
  table.appendChild(row)
  for (let j = 0; j < Columns; j++) {
      var col = document.createElement("td")
      row.appendChild(col)
      col.id = i + "" + j;
      col.onclick = function() {
          console.clear()
          console.log(i, j)
      }    
  }
}
```

```css
tr, td{
  border: 1px solid;
  min-height: 60px;
  min-width: 60px;  
}
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```

If you can't use `let` (maybe because it is ES6), you can use the common `var`, but then you'll need to `bind` the values on the function, as the code below shows:

```js
var Columns = 3
var rows = 3
var table = document.getElementById("table")

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {  
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.textContent = "row " + i;
  table.appendChild(row)
  for (var j = 0; j < Columns; j++) {
      var col = document.createElement("td")
      row.appendChild(col)
      col.id = i + "" + j;
      col.onclick = function(rowI, colJ) {
          console.clear()
          console.log(rowI, colJ)
      }.bind(this, i, j) //bind parameters -> this is the context
  }
}
```

```css
tr, td{
  border: 1px solid;
  min-height: 60px;
  min-width: 60px;  
}
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```